# Java set string value with JSTL c tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to set a String value from session. I want something like that:

```
<%
    String getReactive = <c:out value="${result}"></c:out>;
%>
```

I know it not gonna works. But I need something similar to this:

```
<%
    String getReactive =  ics.GetVar("result");
%>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a c:set attribute available

```
<c:set var="getReactive" value="${result}"  />
```

you can also set *scope* attribute and define the scope of the variable you set. Accessing the variable further down would be simply by

```
<c:out value="${getReactive}"/>
```

the other way around is to use the implicit session object so simply

```
<%
    String getReactive =  (String) session.getAttribute("result");
%>
```

Comment: ok, thats right but I need something like ´String getReactive = c.out("result");´. It's possible isn't it?

Comment: the concept exists, the syntax is different. you have a session object available in the scriptlets. You can check my edited answer, its the same semantics, as you suggest in the comment. c:out does just that, iterates to scopes, searching for the value with the given key